# Haskell: how to get the common words

Tags: haskell

I am trying to do drop common words function, but I do not know how to get or find the common word list. Do I need to create a common words list? Thank you

The question :

```
Takes a list of strings and drops any word that is within the top 20  
most commonly used in English. Returns a list of strings without those words.
```

the result like :

```
dropCommonWords ["the","planet","of","the","apes"]
["planet","apes"]
```

here my dropletters code

```
dropletters xs = filter (\x -> x `elem` ['a'..'z'] ) xs
```

Comment: Well it is almost equivalent, except that you replace `['a'..'z']` with the top 20 words, like `["a", "the", "and"]`. And perhaps you need some way to make sure that uppercase and titlecase common words are dropped as well.

Comment: Not my place, but are trying to simultaneously learn 3+ languages? You may want to narrow your focus. I can't see spreading your time that thin benefiting you in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a list of the common words and then you filter those which are not element of that list:

```
dropCommonWords xs = filter (\x -> x `notElem` common ) xs
  where common = ["the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in", "that", "have", "I", "it", "for", "not", "on", "with", "he", "as", "you", "do", "at"]
```

Result:

```
Prelude> dropCommonWords ["the","planet","of","the","apes"]
["planet","apes"]
```

Comment: can I ask another question, I am trying do countCommonWords to count how many common words for the ["the","planet","of","the","apes"] list , I try use  countCommonWords xs  = map(\w -> (head w) common) $ group $ sort  xs 
where common = ["the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in", "that", "have", "I", "it", "for", "not", "on", "with", "he", "as", "you","at","do"]
but here is error shows Variable not in scope: group :: t0 -> [[[[Char]] -> b]] did I miss something ? thank you

Comment: `dropCommonWords xs = length $ filter (\x -> x \`notElem\` common ) xs
  where common = ["the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in", "that", "have", "I", "it", "for", "not", "on", "with", "he", "as", "you", "do", "at"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use basic recursion for this:

```
import Data.Char

dropCommonWords :: [String] -> [String]
dropCommonWords [] = []
dropCommonWords (x:xs)
    | map toLower x `notElem` commonWords = x : dropCommonWords xs
    | otherwise = dropCommonWords xs
    where commonWords = ["the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in", "that", "have", "I", "it", "for", "not", "on", "with", "he", "as", "you", "do", "at"]
```

Which also converts every word to lowercase before hand with `map toLower x`, since you could get strings such as `"THE"`, and that counts as a common word, just a different case.

Here is the behavior of the above code:

```
*Main> dropCommonWords ["the","planet","of","the","apes"]
["planet","apes"]
*Main> dropCommonWords ["THE","planet","of","the","apes"]
["planet","apes"]
```

**Note:** Using `filter` is better here, I didn't post it since the above answer already mentioned it.